# Transfer data using prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to swift and firebase services,
I'm using fire store data base as my database and I have a  first table view that reads all the data and put it in a nice tableview. every document in my table view has a sub collection. when a user press a row I want it to open a second table view with the sub collection.

this is my prepare for segue code :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let indexPath = tableViewDishes.indexPathForSelectedRow {

   db.collection("Restaurants").document("Applebees").collection("Menu").document(sections[indexPath.section].sectionName!).collection("Dishes").document(sections[indexPath.section].listofDishes![indexPath.row].DishName).collection("Options").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {print(error)}
            else {

                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                    //adding all the data to an array called myOption

                }
            }
        }

        let selectedDishTableViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedDishViewController
        selectedDishTableViewController.myOption = self.myOption
        selectedDishTableViewController.dish = self.sections[indexPath.section].listofDishes?[indexPath.row]
        selectedDishTableViewController.sectionName = sections[indexPath.section].sectionName!
        self.myOption.removeAll()
    }
}
```

the issue is that once my code reach the db.collection line it jumps right away to after the for loop when myOption is a empty array and only then it comes back and appending objects to my array.

that cause the first time I press a row get an empty second table view and when I go back and press it again I get the required information.

Comment: All your line `db.collection(...)` is doing an async call I guess. That it's really enters the closure (where you wrote `for document in querySnapshot!.documents`) AFTER. Call `performSegue()` only after it has done the query.

Answer (score 0):

*db.collection()* does some async work, so all this code:

```
let selectedDishTableViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedDishViewController
selectedDishTableViewController.myOption = self.myOption
selectedDishTableViewController.dish = self.sections[indexPath.section].listofDishes?[indexPath.row]
selectedDishTableViewController.sectionName = sections[indexPath.section].sectionName!
self.myOption.removeAll()
```

should be right before the for loop where you set *myOption* array. That way, everything will be set up once the database has retrieved all the data and you have made all the setup inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let indexPath = tableViewDishes.indexPathForSelectedRow {

   db.collection("Restaurants").document("Applebees").collection("Menu").document(sections[indexPath.section].sectionName!).collection("Dishes").document(sections[indexPath.section].listofDishes![indexPath.row].DishName).collection("Options").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {print(error)}
            else {

                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                    //adding all the data to an array called myOption

                }

        let selectedDishTableViewController = segue.destination as! SelectedDishViewController
        selectedDishTableViewController.myOption = self.myOption
        selectedDishTableViewController.dish = self.sections[indexPath.section].listofDishes?[indexPath.row]
        selectedDishTableViewController.sectionName = sections[indexPath.section].sectionName!
        self.myOption.removeAll()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since its an Async call you might have to write the **selectedDishTableViewController**  segue in the callback.

***Recommendation*** : Seque delegate method should be simple and should not be handling all these db operation try to optimise it.

Comment: That won't work because viewdidload of the second tableview is called before the async db.collection()...getdocuments()
any thoughts on how to fix that?